# How to run docker inside an lxc container?

Tags: arch-linux, docker, lxc, container

I have unprivileged lxc container on Arch host created like this:

`lxc-create -n test_arch11 -t download -- --dist archlinux --release current --arch amd64`

And it doesn't run docker. What I did inside a container:

1. Installed docker from Arch repos `pacman -S docker`
2. Tried to run a hello-world container `docker run hello-world`
3. Got the next error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:297: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker: permission denied\"": unknown.
>
> ERRO[0037] error waiting for container: context canceled

What is wrong and how to make docker work inside a container?

Comment: Are you running the command as `root`?  If not, did you add your user to the `docker` group and logout/login?  Non-root users cannot run docker containers "out of the box".

Comment: @AndyDalton, tried both, neither worked.

Comment: To clarify, you're running docker inside the LXC container?

Comment: @AndyDalton, yes

Answer (score 0):

Because `lxc` and `docker` are using the same kind of isolation ( aka kernel namespace ) , you can not run docker in a **unprivileged** lxc .

You lxc container must have privilege .

But you can run docker in regular virtual machine ( kvm , virtualbox , ... )

Comment: But I could, it worked like several months ago and now after many updates it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for me with adding a flag to the grub config. Here's the source: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CGroupsV2#Upgrade.2Fcompatibility_impact

Follow These Steps:

1- Edit /etc/default/grub

2- Add the following flag in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line: systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0

3- Then : grub2-mkconfig

4- Restart your PC